# .split(",") separating every character of a string

Tags: python, string, csv

At some point of the program I ask it to take the user's text input and separate the text according to it's commas, and then I `",".join` it again in a txt file. The idea is to have a list with all the comma separated information.

The problem is that, apparently, when I `",".join` it, it separates every single character with commas, so if I've got the string `info1,info2` it separates, getting `info1 | info2`, but then, when joining it back again it ends like `i,n,f,o,1,,,i,n,f,o,2,` which is highly unconfortable, since it get's the text back from the txt file to show it to the user later in the program. Can anyone help me with that?

```
        categories = open('c:/digitalLibrary/' + connectedUser + '/category.txt', 'a')
        categories.write(BookCategory + '\n')
        categories.close()
        categories = open('c:/digitalLibrary/' + connectedUser + '/category.txt', 'r')
        categoryList = categories.readlines()
        categories.close()

            for category in BookCategory.split(','):
                for readCategory in lastReadCategoriesList:
                    if readCategory.split(',')[0] == category.strip():
                        count = int(readCategory.split(',')[1])
                        count += 1
                        i = lastReadCategoriesList.index(readCategory)
                        lastReadCategoriesList[i] = category.strip() + "," + str(count).strip()
                        isThere = True
                if not isThere:
                    lastReadCategoriesList.append(category.strip() + ",1")
                isThere = False

            lastReadCategories = open('c:/digitalLibrary/' + connectedUser + '/lastReadCategories.txt', 'w')
            for category in lastReadCategoriesList:
                if category.split(',')[0] != "" and category != "":
                    lastReadCategories.write(category + '\n')
            lastReadCategories.close()

        global finalList

        finalList.append({"Title":BookTitle + '\n', "Author":AuthorName + '\n', "Borrowed":IsBorrowed + '\n', "Read":readList[len(readList)-1], "BeingRead":readingList[len(readingList)-1], "Category":BookCategory + '\n', "Collection":BookCollection + '\n', "Comments":BookComments + '\n'})

        finalList = sorted(finalList, key=itemgetter('Title'))

        for i in range(len(finalList)):
            categoryList[i] = finalList[i]["Category"]
            toAppend = (str(i + 1) + ".").ljust(7) + finalList[i]['Title'].strip()
            s.append(toAppend)

        categories = open('c:/digitalLibrary/' + connectedUser + '/category.txt', 'w')
        for i in range(len(categoryList)):
            categories.write(",".join(categoryList[i]))
        categories.close()
```

Comment: Share your code, so we can place the error you are having

Comment: sure, sorry, forgot to do so

Comment: ok, there is the important part of the code, if you need anything else just let me know.

Comment: the BookCategory variable is created by getting a string variable from an entrybox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should pass `''.join()` a list, you are passing in a single string instead.

Strings are sequences too, so `''.join()` treats every character as a separate element instead:

```
>>> ','.join('Hello world')
'H,e,l,l,o, ,w,o,r,l,d'
>>> ','.join(['Hello', 'world'])
'Hello,world'
```